# python wait till something in postgres database changes

Tags: python

I have a simple postgres database, here's an example table

| id | created_at | whatever |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-22 21:47:20.159781 | something |
| 2 | 2020-12-22 22:13:46.872718 | anything |

how can I do that whenever something changes in it, it triggers a function in my script?

Comment: The standard approach is to check the database for changes every so often (perhaps by adding a `last_modified` column in your table, and fetching rows that have been modified since the last time you checked). Postgres does support calling PG_SQL functions when tables are modified, but I don't know off the top of my head how you would get those to trigger your python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has the `notify` and `listen` procedures you can read up on here: [notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-notify.html) and [listen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-listen.html). Their use in Python is best (and I believe only) through [pyscopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

`pip install psycopg2`

```py
import select
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions


cnct = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
cnct.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

cursor = cnct.cursor()
cursor.execute("LISTEN channel;")
print("Pending notification from 'channel'...")


while True:
    if select.select([cnct],[],[],5) == ([],[],[]):
        print("Channel timed out.")
    else:
        cnct.poll()
        while cnct.notifies:
            notif = cnct.notifies.pop(0)
            print("Received NOTIFY:", notif.pid, notif.channel, notif.payload)
```

Forgot to mention!: This information was from what I versed myself with on the [Psycopg2 Documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) and you might need to more elaborately familiarize yourself with using Pyscopg2 there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, appreciate it. I'm actually using asyncpg as I'm more of an async guy, I think the equivalent for those functions is [`asyncpg.add_listener`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?#asyncpg.connection.Connection.add_listener), I'm not sure tho

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have figured that too; and you're very welcome! Seems to be the similar mechanism, yes.