# Django updates view based on database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, datatables

My issue seems pretty simple but I found it difficult since I'm extremely new to HTML / CSS / Django.

I have a postgresql database that is being updated continuously by another microservice. What I want to do is simply display the table in a HTML page (with https://datatables.net/ for example) and keep on updating it. I've found that we can create websocket connection when we reach the html page via channels but all the tutorial online are about chatbot.

I've managed to do it via a websocket/consumer:

```py
class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
   def connect(self):
      self.accept()
      while True:
         #get the entire info from my db table 
         info = list(infoDB.objects.value())
         self.send(json...(info..))
```

I keep on receiving the information in my HTML page (which is what I wanted), the only problem is I'm getting EVERYTHING from the table + I'm having hard time replacing correctly the initial table with the new one.

Here is my HTML page:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="En">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

    <table id="table_id" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    </table>
  <script>
  const socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/info_co/')
  socket.onmessage = function(e){

      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

      const table = document.getElementById("table_id");

      for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++)
      {
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
          for (let key in data.message[i]){
              var cell = newRow.insertCell(i);

              cell.innerHTML = data.message[i][key];
          }
      }

      var table = $('<table id="table_id" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">');
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var arrheader = ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3','col 4', 'col 5','col 6'];
    var array = data.message;

    for (var j = 0; j < arrheader.length; j++) {
      tr.append($('<th>').text(arrheader[j]));
    }
    table.append(tr);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      table.append(
        $('<tr>').append(
          $('<td>').text(array[i].elem_a),
          $('<td>').text(array[i].elem_b),
          $('<td>').text(array[i].elem_c),
          $('<td>').text(array[i].elem_d),
          $('<td>').text(array[i].elem_e),
          $('<td style="color: green">').text(array[i].elem_f)
        ));

    }

    //table.css("border", "solid");
    //document.querySelector('#table_id').innerHTML = table;
    //document.getElementById('table_id').innerHTML = table;
    $('#table_id').replaceWith(table);
    //$('body').append(table);
  }
            $("#table_id").DataTable({
                        paging : true,
                        pagingLength: 10,
                        lengthChange: true,
                        autoWidth: true,
                        searching: true,
                        bInfo: true,
                        bSort : true,
                        });
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Is there a more straightforward way of doing it ? Is it a good way to keep doing

```py
list(infoDB.objects.value())
```

in a WHILE TRUE loop?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430499/6036546) will help you.

Comment: @Besworks im familiar with this but i don't know if sending notify each time we have a change is the best approach + i'll have to go through my entire table (in HTML) to identify and make the change of the correct cell. In addition, this makes use of python in html (which i did not know was possible lol), i'll still have a look at it, ty

Comment: You wouldn't use python in html, you would subscribe to the notifications in your back-end python code and push the updates over your websocket to your front-end. I'm not really familiar with django though so I have no idea how you would go about implementing that.